# Big Oh,small Oh and Big theta relations

Tags: algorithm, math, asymptotic-complexity, calculus

If a function f(x)=O(g(x)), then there is a chance that f(x)=Ω(g(x)) and f(x)= ϴ(g(x)),but if f(x)=o(g(x)), is it possible that f(x)=Ω(g(x)),or f(x)=ω(g(x))?

Comment: this is programming related how? maybe try the math stack exchange site

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

We give some formal definitions:

```
f(n) = o(g(n))
<=> forall c > 0 exists k > 0 s.t. 0 <= f(n) < cg(n) forall n >= k.
<=> g(n) = ω(f(n))

f(n) = O(g(n))
<=> exists c > 0 exists k > 0 s.t. 0 <= f(n) < cg(n) forall n >= k.
<=> g(n) = Ω(f(n))

f(n) = ϴ(g(n))
<=> f(n) = O(g(n)) and g(n) = O(f(n))
```

Assume `f(n) = o(g(n))`. Question 1: can `f(n) = Ω(g(n))`? If so, then there must exist `c, k` such that for all `n >= k`, `0 <= g(n) < cf(n)`. From the assumption we know that for all `c'` there exists some `k'` such that for all `n >= k'`, `0 <= f(n) < cg(n)`. Let `k'' = max(k, k')`. We must have:

```
0 <= g(k'') < cf(k'')
0 <= f(k'') < c'g(k'')
=> 0 <= g(k'') < cc'g(k'')
```

This must hold for any choice of `c' > 0`. All we know about `c` is that one exists; but as long as `f(n)` and `g(n)` are strictly greater than zero, we know there must be a some smallest `c` which works. Let `c''` be the smallest valid choice of `c` at `k''`. Then we can choose `c' = 1/c''`. Therefore we would require

```
0 < g(k'') < g(k'')
```

Which is always false. Therefore, as long as `f(n)` and `g(n)` aren't (eventually) equal to zero, we cannot simultaneously have `f(n) = o(g(n))` and `f(n) = Ω(g(n))`.

Since `f(n) = ω(g(n))` implies `f(n) = Ω(g(n))`, and we know the latter not to be true in light of our assumption, then we can safely answer Question 2 in the negative as well.